# in vue.js i am trying to get row count but it returning null

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

im trying to get row cout but returning 0 only.

my code

```
 <template>
       <div>
         <p>{{ resultCount }}</p>
       </div>
  </template>
     
     <script>
     import axios from "axios";
     export default {
       data() {
         return {
           registerlist: [],
         };
       },
      async asyncData({ $axios }) {
         let { data } = await $axios.$get("/Businessregisterlist");
         // console.log(response)
         return {
           registerlist: data,
         };
       },
       computed: {
         resultCount() {
           return Object.keys(this.registerlist).length;
         },
       },
     };
     </script>
```

Comment: in which place do you call asyncData function, because i just see the declaration only (but not called anywhere in the code)

Comment: @gijoe is there is any batter way to use count row, please tell me , i used asyncData for registration page , i just copied here

Comment: if you want asyncData to be called automatically when the component loads, then you can register a lifecycle method which will be called automatically. You can use the mounted lifecycle method. So after the computed property write async mounted() { await this.asyncData(); }

Comment: @gijoe for batter understand can you post your answer please

Comment: I think if you just remove the parameter {$axios} in function "async asyncData" and call the await $axios without the $ sign like await axios then you will be ok

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you return a property in asyncData, you should not have it in data property of the component instance, instead the later will override the returned with asyncData.

```js
  <script>
     import axios from "axios";
     export default {
      async asyncData({ $axios }) {
         let { data } = await $axios.$get("/Businessregisterlist");
         // console.log(response)
         return {
           registerlist: data,
         };
       },
       computed: {
         resultCount() {
           return Object.keys(this.registerlist).length;
         },
       },
     };
     </script>
```

```html
<template>
       <div>
         <p>{{ resultCount }}</p>
       </div>
  </template>
```